# How to know when TextToSpeech is finished with speaking?

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I am working Text to Speech for Android application. I am getting confusion on finding a method that to be called when Text to Speech was completed. I tried to call the following methods but the finished was doesn't called, Please have a look into the following code and suggest me.

```
 tts= new TextToSpeech(MainActivity.this, new OnInitListener() {

         @Override
         public void onInit(int status) {

             tts.setOnUtteranceCompletedListener(new OnUtteranceCompletedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onUtteranceCompleted(final String utteranceId) {
                            System.out.println("Completed");

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                        //UI changes
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

         }
        });
```

Please suggest me. I am using API Level 17.

---

**Edit:**

Minimum API level is 12;

And I got the following error in console:

```
01-30 09:19:14.149: E/ActivityThread(660): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService

    has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40ce0ef0 that was originally bound here
01-30 09:19:14.149: E/ActivityThread(660): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40ce0ef0 that was originally bound here
01-30 09:19:14.149: E/ActivityThread(660):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
01-30 09:19:14.149: E/ActivityThread(660):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
01-30 09:19:14.149: E/ActivityThread(660):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
01-30 09:19:14.149: E/ActivityThread(660):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
01-30 09:19:14.149: E/ActivityThread(660):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
01-30 09:19:14.149: E/ActivityThread(660):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
01-30 09:19:14.149: E/ActivityThread(660):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
01-30 09:19:14.149: E/ActivityThread(660):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
01-30 09:19:14.149: E/ActivityThread(660):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
01-30 09:19:14.149: E/ActivityThread(660):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
01-30 09:19:14.149: E/ActivityThread(660):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
01-30 09:19:14.149: E/ActivityThread(660):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
01-30 09:19:14.149: E/ActivityThread(660):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
01-30 09:19:14.149: E/ActivityThread(660):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
01-30 09:19:14.149: E/ActivityThread(660):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
01-30 09:19:14.149: E/ActivityThread(660):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
01-30 09:19:14.149: E/ActivityThread(660):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
01-30 09:19:14.169: E/StrictMode(660): null
01-30 09:19:14.169: E/StrictMode(660): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40ce0ef0 that was originally bound here
01-30 09:19:14.169: E/StrictMode(660):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
01-30 09:19:14.169: E/StrictMode(660):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
01-30 09:19:14.169: E/StrictMode(660):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
01-30 09:19:14.169: E/StrictMode(660):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
01-30 09:19:14.169: E/StrictMode(660):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
01-30 09:19:14.169: E/StrictMode(660):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
01-30 09:19:14.169: E/StrictMode(660):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
01-30 09:19:14.169: E/StrictMode(660):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
01-30 09:19:14.169: E/StrictMode(660):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
01-30 09:19:14.169: E/StrictMode(660):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
01-30 09:19:14.169: E/StrictMode(660):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
01-30 09:19:14.169: E/StrictMode(660):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
01-30 09:19:14.169: E/StrictMode(660):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
01-30 09:19:14.169: E/StrictMode(660):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
01-30 09:19:14.169: E/StrictMode(660):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
01-30 09:19:14.169: E/StrictMode(660):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
01-30 09:19:14.169: E/StrictMode(660):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is not in `onUtteranceComplete` function , its most likely get called, but you're trying to print the output to `System.out` , please use `android.utils.Log("tag", "success")` instead and see what happens.

Also You need to set UtteranceID to get `onUtteranceComplete` to work
before  calling `tts.speak` method. so to sum up:

```
            TextToSpeech tts= new TextToSpeech(MainActivity.this, new OnInitListener() {

         @Override
         public void onInit(int status) {

             tts.setOnUtteranceCompletedListener(new OnUtteranceCompletedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onUtteranceCompleted(final String utteranceId) {
                            System.out.println("Completed");

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                        //UI changes
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

         }
    });
    Map<String,String> ttsParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
    ttsParams.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID,
            MainActivity.this.getPackageName());

    mTts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, ttsParams);
```

And the exception you're getting has nothing to do with the `onUtteranceComplete` method, if it is because of tts engine most likely you're not requesting to destroy your instance when finishing your activity.

To fix that add

```
@Override
onDestroy(){
super.onDestroy();
mTts.shutdown(); //mTts is your TextToSpeech Object
}
```

To your activity class

Comment: Thanks for your response, I used Log.w("tag", "success"); to print it. Still it doesn't came  in the console

Comment: Now it definetly have to work , I forget about tts parameters. it wouldn't get called without them

Comment: Okay, Thank you. I will try to check this.

Comment: Finally I did it, Thanks for all your support

Answer (score 2):

easy way

```
textToSpeech=new TextToSpeech(this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
    @Override
    public void onInit(int status) {
        if (status==TextToSpeech.SUCCESS){
            int result=textToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);

            if (result==TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA||result==TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED){
                Log.i("TextToSpeech","Language Not Supported");
            }

            textToSpeech.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(new UtteranceProgressListener() {
                @Override
                public void onStart(String utteranceId) {
                    Log.i("TextToSpeech","On Start");
                }

                @Override
                public void onDone(String utteranceId) {
                    Log.i("TextToSpeech","On Done");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(String utteranceId) {
                    Log.i("TextToSpeech","On Error");
                }
            });

        }else {
            Log.i("TextToSpeech","Initialization Failed");
        }
    }
});

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    textToSpeech.speak(text,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null,TextToSpeech.ACTION_TTS_QUEUE_PROCESSING_COMPLETED);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From API level 15 you have to use `setOnUtteranceProgressListener` instead of `setOnUtteranceCompletedListener`

Check the [official doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#setOnUtteranceCompletedListener%28android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.OnUtteranceCompletedListener%29)

Comment: Can you please post some snippet? Actually I am getting an error when I try to use setOnUtteranceProgressListener. Under suggessions it asking me to change this to setOnUtteranceCompletedListener.

Comment: whats your apps' `minsdkversion`??

Comment: minmum sdk is 12; and I am running it on 4.2 emulator. Still it is not calling after the speech is done and even before start.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(tts.myTTS.isSpeaking())
```

You get a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

I found "utterance" is for synth files.

For speaking Im using **while(!utteranceDone){thread.sleep...}** and this code:

```
                                brTTS = new BroadcastReceiver(){
                                public void onReceive(Context p1, Intent p2) {
                                    //Log.d(TAG,"TTS ACTION_TTS_QUEUE_PROCESSING_COMPLETED, p2.getAction()="+p2.getAction()+", ? "+TextToSpeech.ACTION_TTS_QUEUE_PROCESSING_COMPLETED);
                                    if (p2.getAction().equals(TextToSpeech.ACTION_TTS_QUEUE_PROCESSING_COMPLETED) && tts != null) {
                                        utteranceDone=true;
                                    }
                                }
                            };
                            registerReceiver(brTTS, new IntentFilter(TextToSpeech.ACTION_TTS_QUEUE_PROCESSING_COMPLETED));
```